# What segment code do

Tags: jquery, wordpress

```
window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
    imgurl = jQuery('img',html).attr('src');
    jQuery('#adimage').val(imgurl);
    tb_remove();
}
```

I not know what do this segment code, most interesting is `imgurl = jQuery('img',html).attr('src');` code searching in all document img `id` ant src `url` ?

Comment: The docs are quite clear in this aspect. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1

Answer (score 3):

This is pretty straight forward. It will return all `img` elements that are descendants of html, `html` here is the context. and then only return the `src` attribute of first node in the collection, chaining it with `attr` will only return the src of first node.

```
imgurl = jQuery('img', html).attr('src');
```

Comment: Nope. `html` is passed as a parameter to the function, it is a variable.

Comment: Oops, yeah I didn't look the parameter. Fixed.

Comment: Very clean explanation. +1

Answer (score 0):

`imgurl = jQuery('img',html).attr('src');`

This code specifically is looking to find an img tag and get the src attribute from it and assign that to the var imgurl.

The context it is searching in I think is whatever you are passing in as `html`

Comment: how this function is called ?